# Failed to bind properties under 'spring.datasource' to javax.sql.DataSource

Tags: java, database, spring, eclipse, spring-boot

I create an application in `Spring Boot 2.0.0`. I use `HikariCP` by default. The `application.yml` file for the `PostgreSQL` database looked like this

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    jdbcUrl: jdbc:postgresql:database
    username: root
    password: root
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    # Hikari
    poolName: SpringBootHikariCP
    maximumPoolSize: 5
    minimumIdle: 3
    maxLifetime: 2000000
    connectionTimeout: 30000
    idleTimeout: 30000
    pool-prepared-statements: true
    max-open-prepared-statements: 250
    connection-test-query: SELECT 1
eclipse-link:
  database-platform: org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.PostgreSQLPlatform
  generate-dll: true
  show-sql: true
  weaving: static
```

The PostgreSQL application works without a problem. After I tried to change the database to H2, I changed the data to

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    jdbcUrl: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
    username: sa
    password:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    # Hikari
    poolName: SpringBootHikariCP
    maximumPoolSize: 5
    minimumIdle: 3
    maxLifetime: 2000000
    connectionTimeout: 30000
    idleTimeout: 30000
    pool-prepared-statements: true
    max-open-prepared-statements: 250
    connection-test-query: SELECT 1

spring.h2.console:
  enabled: true
  path: /h2

eclipse-link:
  database-platform: org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.H2Platform
  generate-dll: true
  show-sql: true
  weaving: static
```

And the configuration bean looks like this https://pastebin.com/MwTJE8Kp

He throws out during compilation

```
2018-04-15 18:38:56.395 DEBUG 3592 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : Driver class org.h2.Driver not found in Thread context class loader TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader
  context: ROOT
  delegate: true
----------> Parent Classloader:
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2
, trying classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2
2018-04-15 18:38:56.406 ERROR 3592 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : Failed to load driver class org.h2.Driver from HikariConfig class classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2
2018-04-15 18:38:56.412 ERROR 3592 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint]: Factory method 'healthEndpoint' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$30a19622]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindException: Error creating bean with name 'getDatasource': Could not bind properties to 'HikariDataSource' : prefix=spring.datasource, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'spring.datasource' to javax.sql.DataSource
2018-04-15 18:38:56.465  WARN 3592 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
```

As long as I'm using the PostgreSQL database, everything is OK, but when I change the base to H2, it throws an error.

Comment: Looks like a classpath issue. Did you make sure that `org.h2.Driver` is in the classpath?
I can help more if you provided your pom.xml or build.gradle file

Comment: I added to build.gradle runtime("com.h2database:h2")

Comment: Because your configuration is wrong. You are using the old configuration names (Spring Boot <= 1.3) where as you should now be using the vendor (hikari) specific properties. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html (basically everything NOT defined at the `spring.datasource` level is vendor specific.

Comment: And why does the same configuration work for PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0):

@Alain-Michel-Commoue was getting near: The HikariCP.jar is a missing dependency in the classpath. You can get it easily by:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.12.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```